# Shifted DE Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I just want to know what kind of a shift the *$-15$* causes in this equation:
$P' = 0.08P(1-\frac{P}{1000})-15$

Comment: what is being shifted?

Comment: @abel sorry, forgot to put it in somehow.

Answer (score 0):

the special solutions $0$ and $100$ are going to change. find the new constant solutions by solving $$0.08P(1-P/1000) = 15.$$ let the smaller of the solution be $P_1=250.$ if $P(0) < 250,$ then there is a time $T_f$ you can compute using the same formula so that $P(T_f) = 0.$  that is the whole population will be gone in that time called the extinction time.

Comment: I think you mean $1000$, not $100$.

Comment: @abel so the -15 basically just indicates that the equation ends after a certain time based on the value of P? Or something along those lines?  I don't have to solve anything I just have to explain what -15 means.

Comment: It doesn't "end" unless you interpret $P$ as a population, which becomes extinct when it hits $0$.  That only happens if $P(0)$ happens to be less than $250$.  If $P(0) > 250$ the population still approaches a stable equilibrium.